# Is Python's pipenv slow?

Tags: python, pipenv

I tried switching from `venv` & `conda` to `pipenv` to manage my virtual environments, but one thing I noticed about `pipenv` that it's oddly slow when it's doing "Locking" and it gets to the point where it stops executing for "Running out of time". Is it usually this slow or is it just me? Also, could you give me some advice regarding how to make it faster?

Comment: At the very least, `pipenv` does a poor job of logging what exactly it is *doing* during the seemingly interminable "Locking..." phase.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, I've found pipenv's locking and dependency resolution is terrible. For what it's worth, I've moved to just `venv` and [poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry). The poetry github has a section talking about pipenv, and also note that poetry is a little less concerned with your actual virtual environment, and more about dependency management/packaging.

Comment: Poetry looks very promising and well documented, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: are you happy with poetry? I found it very focused on 'installable' packages

Comment: We have done some performance enhancements to `pipenv` in recent times, including a big install optimization which released `2022.8.31`.  For an independent comparison of benchmarks, please have a look at:  https://lincolnloop.github.io/python-package-manager-shootout/

Comment: Poetry's README.md no longer has a section about Pipenv (since https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/5561 was merged). The removal was because "poetry is big enough and mature enough to stand on its own merits".

Answer (score 17):

Pipenv is literally a joke. I spent 30 minutes staring at "Locking", which eventually fails after exactly 15 minutes, and I tried two times.
The most meaningless thirty minutes in my life.

Was my Pipfile complex? No. I included "flask" with "flake8" + "pylint" + "mypy" + "black".

Every time someone tries to fix the "dependency management" of Python, it just gets worse.
I'm expecting Poetry to solve this, but who knows.

Maybe it's time to move on to typed languages for web development.

Comment: The latest version of pipenv which is currently `2022.8.31` and has a number of optimizations and bug fixes since your comment over 2 years ago.

Comment: Downvoted: this is a rant, not an answer; also "Pipenv is literally a joke": no, it's not, it's figuratively a joke.

Comment: @AkiRoss No offense, but it is still an answer to the OP's "Is it usually this slow or is it just me?", and I answered, "It's not just you, I wasted many minutes using it!" :)

Comment: No offense taken. I don't think that "it's not only you" is a valid answer to a problem and a comment would have been enough for that ;) The rant, while I get and share the frustration, it's not useful to solve the problem.

Comment: @Matteius any way to update the "Locking..." message to something less anger inducing :) I just stopped the install multiple times because I didn't understand what "Locking" meant. I think it actually means "Downloading...25% Complete on such-and-such a package" and then later "Locking...". This was a vastly different experience coming from npm, maven, etc and so was very confusing.

Answer (score 6):

Long-time ago, it was slow for reason. But now, it is slow for no reason:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3827

Please see this issue, there are a lot of similar issues about that ridiculous locking performance. But as you see, they call it "Enhancement". Well, forgive me, WTF, it is literally a bug.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of issues, it's performing very poorly! I don't know why people kept recommending it for me. However, I think I'll give [poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry) a shot and see how it's doing.

Comment: Myself and another developer took on the maintenance of pipenv at the start of this year and have been making a number of improvements.  For an independent comparison of latest benchmarks, please have a look at: lincolnloop.github.io/python-package-manager-shootout

Answer (score 4):

try using `--skip-lock` like this :

`pipenv install --skip-lock`

Note : do not skip-lock when going in production

Answer (score 1):

I have observed faster turn-around times with the following flow.

```
pipenv --rm  && rm -rf Pipfile.lock && pipenv install --dev .
```